# React: How to pass input value to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm stuck with something.

I have 3 components, Home, UserForm and Input, they're nested as described. I need to have the values of the input as the user types on the **home** component. I can't get it to work.

I need help!

**home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import UserForm from '../components/UserForm';

import './Home.scss';

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            <div className="card-container">
            </div>
            <div className="description-container">
                <div className="form-container">
                    <UserForm />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**UserForm.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import Input from './Input';

export default function UserForm(props) {

    return (
        <div className="user-form">
            <form>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Nome a ser impresso" />
                <Input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}
```

**Input.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './Input.scss';

export default function Input(props) {
    const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('');

    function listenToInput(e) {
        setInputVal(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="input-holder">
            <input
                type={props.type || 'text'}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                value={inputVal}
                onChange={listenToInput}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I advise you to read this document on Lifting State Up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('');
```

To `Home` and pass `inputVal` and `setInputVal` all the way to `Input` as props.

This is called "prop drilling".

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gabriel Pichot said in comment: Refer to [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Use component's props to set input's value

if you need mutate state in your `Home` component, you can move your state from `Input` to `Home`.
Then give the props to the `UserForm`, and give props again to `Input`

a example for how to do it:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        // const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

        function Home() {
            const [inputVal, setInputVal] = React.useState('');
            const [inputVal2, setInputVal2] = React.useState('');

            return (
                <div className="home-container">
                    <div className="card-container">
                    </div>
                    <div className="description-container">
                        <div className="form-container">
                            <UserForm setInputVal={setInputVal} setInputVal2={setInputVal2} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>first input: {inputVal}</p>
                    <p>second input: {inputVal2}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }

        function UserForm(props) {
            return (
                <div className="user-form">
                    <form>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Nome a ser impresso" setInputVal={props.setInputVal} />
                        <Input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" setInputVal={props.setInputVal2} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }

        function Input(props) {
            function listenToInput(e) {
                props.setInputVal(e.target.value);
            }

            return (
                <div className="input-holder">
                    <input
                        type={props.type || 'text'}
                        placeholder={props.placeholder}
                        onChange={listenToInput} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Home></Home>
            , document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
```

#### Other ways (`React.useContext`)

Or you can use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), it can give your state and setState function to the grandchildren component